# Matebook X PRO and Nvidia drivers with Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

Once installing nvidia-390 drivers (or other versions) in my MBXP, I experienced a black screen after the boot.
I managed to resolve the problem going in tty and purging all the Nvidia drivers and removing the xorg file.

The fact is that now, using inxi -G I got this:

```
Graphics:

Card-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620

Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1d12

Display Server: x11 ([X.Org](https://X.Org) 1.19.6 )

drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: modesetting

Resolution: [3000x2000@60.00hz](mailto:3000x2000@60.00hz)

OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)

version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5
```

So I'm not using any type of driver!
What's better to do?
Trying to reinstall Nvidia (I don't know how to make I working) or repairing modesetting?
What's the best for the battery?

Edit: part 2

Even if I set the driver with the driver manager I have no real changes and nvidia-setting doesn't work.
I'm on a fresh Mint 19 installation.